# primary stress of "running repairs" vs. "running order"

Tags: pronunciation, word-stress

I'd like to know why the primary stress falls on the second word of "running **repairs**" but on the first word of "**running** order."

> The computer is in **running order**.
>
> He made **running repairs** to his car.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I suggest you give complete sentences as examples of the two pairs of words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your second sentence, I don't hear any difference in stress on the two words in the definition with pronunciation given in Collins Dictionary:
[Collins "running repairs"](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/running-repairs)

For your first sentence, "The computer is in running order.", I think I would give the two words "running" and "order" equal stress, because the meaning is in the combination of the two words, except in the special case where I am comparing a running computer with one that is not running, or contradicting a claim that the computer is not in running order. In those cases, I might put extra stress on "running".

There is another meaning for "running order", and that is, from Collins dictionary, the order of events in a meeting, and in that case, the stress goes on "running". The meaning there is "order of running"; maybe that is why "running" is stressed: to make clear what is being put in order.

Comment: Look at the stress mark here: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/running-repairs?q=running+repairs

Comment: And https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/running-order?q=running+order

Comment: I have listened to both audio versions in your first link (running repairs), and I can hear no difference in the stress between the two words. There is added stress on the first syllable of both of the words. For your second link (running order), I hear a difference, and it agrees with what I would say, but the only meaning there is the one about the order of events in a meeting, not the other meaning.

Answer (score 1):

To expand a bit on Jack O'Flaherty's answer (with which I entirely agree), the emphasis tends to go on what is important. Here are a few examples, with the emphasis italicized:

> The computer is in *running order*. (The computer works.)
>   I am running *orders* up to the counter. (At a restaurant, for example; I've written down some orders and I'm conveying them to the counter.)
>   Here is the *running* order for the competitors. (A bunch of people are going to run one after the other and be timed, so here is the order in which they are going to run.)
>   I am running *programs* on the computer. (The programs are more important; everyone knows that what you do with programs is run them.)
>   There are some *running programs* on the computer. (Now, we want to make clear that some programs are running, as opposed to there being no programs currently running on the computer.)